# Android Media Player Service not working once published

Tags: java, android

I am using a mediaplayer service to stream mp3 from url. After read all documentation and dozens of posts, following is my last code. This code works properly on all emulators but only works on some devices and, strange behaviour, some of them with same OS (kit kat for example), works in some and others not... Errors were debugged and, looking at logcat, seems that does prepareAsync() properly but never throws onPrepared().
After publishing the app, test devices that were running while debbuging, doesn't stream music too!

```
public class backgroundAudio extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    WifiLock wifiLock;

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {

        mediaPlayer = null;
        String url = "http://www.myserver.com/mystream.mp3"; 
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

        wifiLock.acquire();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            // it takes so long, about a minute...

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
                | IllegalStateException | IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

      /** Called when MediaPlayer is ready */
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            radio0.tabBridge.setStopView();
        }

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
      }

      public void onDestroy() {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
              mediaPlayer.stop();
              mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            wifiLock.release();
          }

      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        stopSelf();
      }
```

related manifest permissions,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Have you tried adding also a [OnErrorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener.html) to see if something went wrong? Also, have you verified that the server is actually reachable from other devices/networks?

Comment: is the build minifyEnabled? If so, try with a build that's not minifyEnabled. Proguard could be causing some issues here

Answer (score 2):

There is no `@Override` annotation on the `onPrepared()` method. Normally it shouldn't be a problem, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Well i will recommend you to use [**EXOPlayer Library**](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) if your r going to use the `MediaPlayer` for Streaming a file. There is a sample on the page too.